# How to make a fancy shortcut on the desktop to my python app?

Tags: python, nokia, maemo, n900

I've made this nice python app that runs when i use "python main.py" in terminal, but going thru the terminal each time is boring :-) how can i make a nice shortcut button with a img to have on my desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here:

http://www.themaemo.com/howto-launch-a-terminal-app-from-a-shortcut/

Basically, you need to create a .desktop file with the execution of the script in the EXEC line